# helm template: how do i assign the result of a template to a variable

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to do something like:

```
{{- $cassandrafullname := template "cassandra.fullname" . -}}
```

but I'm getting this error on a dry run:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: parse error in "cassandra/templates/service.yaml": template: cassandra/templates/service.yaml:1: unexpected <template> in command
```

---

The reason why I have this issue is because I am unable to use the `template cassandra.fullname` within a range, so I'm trying to put the value into a variable and use it in the range instead. So if there's a solution for that, it would also be accepted!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Helm defines an `include` function](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#the-include-function) which is identical to the standard `template`, except that it returns the rendered output instead of outputting it.  You should be able to write

```
{{- $cassandrafullname := include "cassandra.fullname" . -}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of this advice.

Comment: what could be the reason I still get same error after I use include

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does not work with `fromYaml`, so you can't read yaml structs into pipeline operations as usual. A rather big shortcoming. Lots of times I need to filter a list into another list, but this seems impossible with helm:

```
{{- define "sometpl" -}}
- bla: dibla
- oki: doki
{{- end -}}
---
{{- $v := include "sometpl" . | fromYaml }}
some: {{- $v | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

Will give

```
some:
  Error: 'error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array
    into Go value of type map[string]interface {}'
```